# Template IntelliSense

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense, angular-template

I use C# mostly and one thing that I am missing in VSCode is IntelliSense in Angular 2 templates.

I found that there is a solution to this problem [here](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6508), but I couldn't find a way to integrate it into Visual Studio Code.

I need this:
[image]

Is there any way to get IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code for Angular 2 templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone who is looking for this functionality, there is an extension [Angular Language Service VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).

Answer (score 2):

That page you linked details the installation steps:

**Usage in VSCode:**

1. Replace the **typescript.tmLanguage** file under the install location at `Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript/syntaxes` with the version from the TypeScript-TmLanguage repo above (from the ngml branch).
2. Fork the TypeScript repo above, checkout the ngml branch, and build.
3. Open the VSCode global settings, and set the `typescript.tsdk` property to the build location in the prior step (e.g. `/src/typescript/built/local`).
4. To get completions within the template on characters such as <, [, etc. open **typescriptMain.ts** from the `Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript` folder under the VSCode install location, and change the line that calls `registerCompletionItemProvider` to read `vscode_1.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(modeID, completionItemProvider, '.', '<', '(', '[', '\'');`
5. To make changes edit the local TypeScript repo, rebuild, and relaunch VSCode.

Right now, it doesn't look like there's an extension for it, yet - likely due to gaps in the extension API which are currently in development.