# Visual Studio Code intellisense shows ng-model rather than ngModel

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using **Visual Studio Code** for Angular, VS code intelisense shows **ng-model** rather than **ngModel**. Do I need to update something or something else?
Please tell the solution. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 template intellisense in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589915/angular-2-template-intellisense-in-vs-code)

Comment: its different question

Comment: can you post the code block? any errors at run time? have you tried reloading the VS window? does it function normally inside a stackblitz or plunker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, it doesn't look like there's an extension for it, yet - likely due to gaps in the extension API which are currently in development.